# Map the next node of input XML into previous node of XML schema

Tags: biztalk

I have an source and destination schema like following

Source Schema:

```
<Root>
    <STDS>
        <COD>
        <NAM>
        <AGE>
    </STDS>
</Root>
```

Destination Schema::

```
<Root>
    <Students>
        <Code100>
            <Name>
            <Age>
            <Code50>
                <Name>
                <Age>
            </Code50>
        </Code100>
    </Students>
</Root>
```

In the source input, STDS is unbounded. Node COD can have three values 100, 200 and 50. So any STDS node having the COD value = 50, should be added to the STDS with COD value = 100 prior to the current STDS node.

I have an input like.

```
<Root>
    <STDS>
        <COD>200</COD>
        <NAM>ABC</NAM>
        <AGE>20</AGE>
    </STDS>
    <STDS>
        <COD>100</COD>
        <NAM>XYZ</NAM>
        <AGE>21</AGE>
    </STDS>
    <STDS>
        <COD>50</COD>
        <NAM>JJJ</NAM>
        <AGE>22</AGE>
    </STDS>
    <STDS>
        <COD>200</COD>
        <NAM>JKL</NAM>
        <AGE>23</AGE>
    </STDS>
    <STDS>
        <COD>100</COD>
        <NAM>MMM</NAM>
        <AGE>24</AGE>
    </STDS>
        <STDS>
        <COD>50</COD>
        <NAM>NNN</NAM>
        <AGE>25</AGE>
    </STDS>
    </STDS>
        <STDS>
        <COD>50</COD>
        <NAM>LLL</NAM>
        <AGE>26</AGE>
    </STDS>
</Root>
```

I need an output like following

```
<Root>
    <Students>
        <Code200>
            <Name>ABC</Name>
            <Age>20</Age>
        </Code200>
        <Code100>
            <Name>XYZ</Name>
            <Age>21</Age>
            <Code50>
                <Name>JJJ</Name>
                <Age>22</Age>
            </Code50>
        </Code100>
            <Name>XYZ</Name>
            <Age>21</Age>
        </Code100>
        <Code200>
            <Name>JKL</Name>
            <Age>23</Age>
        </Code200>
        </Code100>
            <Name>MMM</Name>
            <Age>24</Age>
            <Code50>
                <Name>NNN</Name>
                <Age>24</Age>
            </Code50>
            <Code50>
                <Name>LLL</Name>
                <Age>25</Age>
            </Code50>
        </Code100>
    </Students>
</Root>
```

I want to achieve this in BizTalk mapper without using custom XSLT.

Comment: Is this is the same map as the other two questions?  You will have to undo the custom xslt, which you should anyway.

Comment: It is a different map, transformation is different in this one. I'm new to BizTalk, I'm not sure If It is achievable by just using BT mapper. I've tried in different ways but been unsuccessful . Can you give an idea for this or any approach to do this in mapper.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is

Link `<COD>` to `<Code50>`, `<Code100>` etc.. through an **Equal Functoid** that tests for 50, 100, etc.

Depending on the composition of the Schemas, you may also have to like `<STDS>` to `<CodeXXX>` through **Looping Functoids**.

Just like the other questions, which you should also switch back to Functoids, this can be done with Functoids only, you just have to try some combinations.

Comment: 90 percent part of it is done by functoids, but when I visit the <COD50> node(s), I need to add it to previous <Code100> and for that I need to access/preserve the previous <COD100>, That part I'm not able to do using functoids.

Comment: @v_kumar Ayayay...is there any way to change the source Xml?  Because that pattern basically misses the whole point of Xml  The 50's should be children of the 100's already.

Comment: @v_kumar Did you investigate if modifying the source Xml is possible?  Also, did this come from a Flat File?  If, there's an important change to make there.

Comment: Yes, source XML comes from a Flat File. I don't think it'd be possible to change that.

Comment: @v_kumar Can you post a sample of the flat file?  It might be possible to preserve the structure coming from there.

Comment: @v_kumar We're you able to modify the Flat File Schema to keep the structure?  of Code is the first field, it will work.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the follow up but I don't think I'll be able to change the structure of FF or the source schema. I had to do it by custom only. It may not ne the best but had to. Thanks!!

Comment: @v_kumar No, you don't need to change the Flat File.  Why can't you change the schema?  It should be part of your BizTalk app?  It just looks like you've made you app way more complicated and risky than it needs to be.